# Fancytree: Add Pagination

Tags: javascript, fancytree

I am using FancyTree plugin to display a couple of filenames. Since I have a large dataset for the tree plugin, I wanted to know if the API support pagination in the tree display. I looked through the API but could not find anything suitable. Is there any way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no such feature. 
It should be possible to implement a simple variant using the existing API though.

See here for related requests: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/169